# Are there any scene removed to make it so short?

Tags: harry-potter, order-of-the-phoenix

Being lengthy book in the Harry Potter series, Order of the Pheonix
is second shortest movie in the Harry Potter series.

Are there any scene removed to make it so short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Order_of_the_Phoenix_(film)#Differences_from_the_book):

- The Quidditch scenes were cut
- The pensieve memory was greatly abbreviated, including eliminating Lily showing up
- The St. Mungo's scene was removed
- Some of Kreacher's scenes were removed, and all of Dobby's actions were given to other characters
- Rita Skeeter's scenes were removed